# $\mathsf{NL}$ vs. $\mathsf{AC}^1$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, logspace, circuit-depth

It is known that $\mathsf{NL} \subseteq \mathsf{AC}^1$ (because $\mathsf{NL}$-complete  problem **PATH** belongs to $\mathsf{AC}^1$).

Are there problems in $\mathsf{AC}^1$ that are unknown to be in $\mathsf{NL}?$

(Here by $\mathsf{AC}^1$ I mean  the class of decision problems solvable by a *uniform* family of Boolean circuits, with polynomial size, logarithmic depth , and unbounded fan-in.)

Comment: LOGCFL-complete problems such as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOGCFL).

Comment: I'd think that $O(\log n)$-width mazes should be $\mathsf{AC}^1$-complete (see here https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0028550 for the problem definition and proof that they are complete for levels of the $\mathsf{AC}^0$ hierarchy). Any such complete problem won't be known to be in $\mathsf{NL}$.